# MariaDB/MySQL: combine rows if fields are NULL

Tags: php, mysql, database, mariadb

let's say I have a table with 6 rows, first is auto-incrementing numeric ID, 2nd is DateTime (automatically set) and the last 4 are sensor-values:

```
ID  DateTime    Val1    Val2    Val3    Val4
1   xxx         20      10      NULL    NULL
2   xxx         NULL    NULL    30      15
3   xxx         23      14      NULL    NULL
4   xxx         25      04      NULL    NULL
5   xxx         12      11      NULL    NULL
6   xxx         NULL    NULL    33      19
```

Way more often the sensordata is automatically written to the database. Perhaps a few times a day manual data is added to Val3 and Val4. Now I have to load the most recent row from the database. If I do this:

```
SELECT Val1,Val2,Val3,Val4 FROM table ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

I get either a row with Val1 and 2 or 3 and 4. Though I need it this way, with the example above in respect:

```
5 | xxx | 12 | 11 | 30 | 15

or

6 | xxx | 12 | 11 | 33 | 19
```

The values from the latest line + the missing values from the last line that had non NULL values. Could somebody be so kind to explain how to do this? Running a MariaDB 10 database on a Raspberry Pi 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of query requires some variable trickery in order to look behind at the last row.

To more concretly show the solution:

```
MariaDB [test] create table test2 (
    id int primary key not null auto_increment, 
    ts timestamp not null default current_timestamp, 
    val1 int,val2 int,val3 int,val4 int
);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.43 sec)

MariaDB [test] insert into test2 (val1,val2,val3,val4) values
    (20,10,null,null),
    (null,null,40,25),
    (23,14,null,null),
    (25,4,null,null),
    (12,11,null,null),
    (null,null,33,19);
Query OK, 6 rows affected (0.07 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [test] select * from (
    select t.id as id, t.ts, 
        @val1 := coalesce(t.val1,@val1) as val1, 
        @val2 := coalesce(t.val2,@val2) as val2, 
        @val3 := coalesce(t.val3,@val3) as val3, 
        @val4 := coalesce(t.val4,@val4) as val4 
    from test2 t, (select @val1 := 0,@val2:=0,@val3:=0,@val4:=0) as start order by id
) x ;

+----+---------------------+------+------+------+------+
| id | ts                  | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 |
+----+---------------------+------+------+------+------+
|  1 | 2017-09-20 06:53:41 | 20   | 10   | 0    | 0    |
|  2 | 2017-09-20 06:53:41 | 20   | 10   | 40   | 25   |
|  3 | 2017-09-20 06:53:41 | 23   | 14   | 40   | 25   |
|  4 | 2017-09-20 06:53:41 | 25   | 4    | 40   | 25   |
|  5 | 2017-09-20 06:53:41 | 12   | 11   | 40   | 25   |
|  6 | 2017-09-20 06:53:41 | 12   | 11   | 33   | 19   |
+----+---------------------+------+------+------+------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will little modify your query as below:

```
SELECT Val1,Val2,Val3,Val4 FROM table where (Val3 and Val4) is not null ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1
```

Hope this helps...!!!

Comment: Sadly, this will give me only the last row that has values in it. The first values still getting NULL'ed. :/

Comment: Looks like I need to load every field alone and combine it later in PHP....

Answer (score 0):

Below query will solve your problem.

```
SELECT
    (SELECT Val1 FROM table where Val1 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) as Val1,
    (SELECT Val2 FROM table where Val2 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) as Val2,
    (SELECT Val3 FROM table where Val3 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) as Val3,
    (SELECT Val4 FROM table where Val4 IS NOT NULL ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1) as Val4;
```